# conditional (theme) language selection at 'runtime'

Tags: multi-language, theme-twenty-ten, language

I have two issues to change the language for the theme at 'runtime'. I'm not sure about my question title, hope my description helps.

I already use a plugin Polylang and there nice features: link pages with equal content but different languages AND configure primary menu for each language AND a language switcher which will be added into the primary menu.

(I also tried xLanguage and xili-language, but they were not confortable for me)

Polylang has very nice features, but I need some more:

- a guestbook, its a page which acts like a guestbook, no content only comments. I need the form, etc. (theme) in two languages, but is only one page
- I have second menu in the footer, there I also want to use different menu elements (names and links) for each language

Is there a possibility to change the language by passing some HTTP GET params (and redirect) and then check the params and change/reload the page with needed language?

I already tried to change the `wordpress_polylang` value in the cookie, but no effect.
I found the reference for [load_theme_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) but there is no parameter to pass an language.

I use Starkers theme, based on twentyten.

//edit:
I found this snippet in the core.php of the polylang plugin, perhaps it would help.

```
// NOTE: I believe there are two ways for a plugin to force the WP language
// as done by xili_language and here: load text domains and reinitialize wp_locale 
//    with the action 'wp'
// as done by qtranslate: define the locale with the action 'plugins_loaded', but
//     in this case, the language must be specified in the url.
function load_textdomains() {
    // sets the current language
    if (!($this->curlang = $this->get_current_language()))
        return; // something went wrong

    // set a cookie to remember the language. check headers have not been sent to avoid ugly error
    if (!headers_sent())
        setcookie('wordpress_polylang', $this->curlang->slug, time() + 31536000 /* 1 year */, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

    // set all our language filters and actions
    $this->add_language_filters();

    // our override_load_textdomain filter has done its job. let's remove it before calling load_textdomain
    remove_filter('override_load_textdomain', array(&$this, 'mofile'));

    // now we can load text domains with the right language
    $new_locale = get_locale();
    foreach ($this->list_textdomains as $textdomain)
        load_textdomain( $textdomain['domain'], str_replace($this->default_locale, $new_locale, $textdomain['mo']));

    // and finally load user defined strings (check first that base64_decode is not disabled)
    if (function_exists('base64_decode')) {
        global $l10n;
        $mo = new MO();
        $reader = new POMO_StringReader(base64_decode(get_option('polylang_mo'.$this->curlang->term_id)));
        $mo->import_from_reader($reader);
        $l10n['pll_string'] = &$mo;
    }

    // reinitializes wp_locale for weekdays and months, as well as for text direction
    global $wp_locale;
    $wp_locale->init();
    $wp_locale->text_direction = get_metadata('term', $this->curlang->term_id, '_rtl', true) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
}
```

Comment: This question can be seen as "close to a follow up" on [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/change-language-by-clicking-a-button).

Comment: [Take a look at this explanation about rewrites by @ChristopherDavis](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api).

Comment: I don't think that redefining `WPLANG` is a solution, because when I dump this constant on every page and switch the languages, the value is always `string(5) "de_DE"`

Comment: And the question is if `WPLANG` would work, where I have to redefine it? I tried it in the header.php of the theme, no effect.

Comment: I will (later that year) write a plugin for that. So if you append `/en` to it, `WP_LANG` will be set to `en_EN` for example. Point is that this has to be a plugin hooked to `plugins_loaded`. Else it's too late.

Comment: Can you tell me in which phase of the request and/or in which file/sourcecode region I have to change the `WPLANG` value? Now I tried to put this into function.php and write this at the end 
`add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_lang_hook');
function my_lang_hook() {
      define("WPLANG", "en-US");
}`
but `WPLANG` value does not change, its always `de_DE`. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Turn off all of your plugins and switch to the default theme to make shure nothing is intercepting. Then read about `define` on php.net.

Comment: I know about the define function. Okay, when it works usually, then the reason could be the polylang plugin. I edit my question, because I found an important snippet (I hope) how the plugin works with language handling. But I don't understand it.

Comment: Why don't you first test this with the default theme and no plugins - as suggested. The current way is plain guessing on both sides.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2590/discussion-between-timaschew-and-kaiser)

Comment: Just go there and ask.

Comment: why you can't post snippet with a concrete example? everything you written until now are only some links an information which are too much general.

Comment: You didn't test it with the defaults or reported back or joined in the chat. So what?

Comment: I did. I set all to default but still don't work and I wrote this in the chat.

Comment: I searched through chat history and can't find any comment from  you there.

Comment: I don't know, then the chat doesn't work thats the conent:okay I deactivated all plugins and switch to twentyeleven theme and define WPLANG at the end of the function.php and dump it, there is no change! I can't change the constanc. There must be an other step which I forget. Please, can you write a complete snippet which will work? So can you please make a concrete example?

Comment: Use Qtranslate (http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) . If I understood your requierments correctly - everything you need can be easily done with that plugin ..

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, realy dirty, but works.

In the core.php file of the polylang plugin I found this stuff:

```
// NOTE: I believe there are two ways for a plugin to force the WP language
// as done by xili_language and here: load text domains and reinitialize wp_locale with the action 'wp'
// as done by qtranslate: define the locale with the action 'plugins_loaded', but in this case, the language must be specified in the url.
function load_textdomains() {
    // sets the current language

    if (!($this->curlang = $this->get_current_language()))
    return; // something went wrong

    // --- modified --> check for guestbook, which should be display in different languages
    $this->check_joined_content();
    ...
}

define("GUESTBOOK_PAGE_ID", "12");
define("GUESTBOOK_HTTP_PARAM", "guestbook_lang");

function check_joined_content() {
    $gl = $_GET[GUESTBOOK_HTTP_PARAM];
    if(isset($gl)) {
        if ($this->curlang->object_id != GUESTBOOK_PAGE_ID) {
            return;
        }
        if ($gl == "de") {
            $this->curlang = $this->get_language("de");
        } else {
            $this->curlang = $this->get_language("en");
        }
    }
}
```

access to the pages via http get params:
`?guestbook_lang=en` and `?guestbook_lang=de`