# How to change the language for the front-end only?

Tags: themes, language

I have installed a wordpress theme, i can see the .mo and .po `/public_html/wp-content/themes/themename/lang`, the language I want to use is available.

Could you please advise on how to use a specific language? I don't want to change the admin language just the theme language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change locale at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-at-runtime)

Answer (score 8):

Well, you actually do not need anything special to have two different languages in the back end and in the front end. I just tested it again on WP 5.1

1. go to the `settings` and set the `Site Language` to the front end laguage, for example - German, then save.
2. go to `Users` and then click edit on your administrator account. There you can set `Language` to English and save. That's it. Your front end will use German as base and the back end will be in English.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still looking for that, here is what you should do since version 4.7

```
function wp_noshor_redefine_locale($locale) {
    if( is_admin() ):
        switch_to_locale('en_US');
    endif;
}
add_filter('init','wp_noshor_redefine_locale');
```

This forces the dashboard to load in English, then you can go to settings, set the language you desire.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the string for `locale`, it holds the current language. And you can exclude the admin from that filter:

```
is_admin() or add_filter( 'locale', function() {
    return 'ar';
});
```

Comment: Actually, I mean how can i activate a specific language for the theme?

Comment: This happens automatically when `locale` matches an existing translation file.

Comment: sorry for bothering as i'm new to WP, but how can i make locale match the translation file?

Comment: By adding the code above to a plugin or your theme’s `functions.php`.

Comment: i have to enter then ar-AR for my theme to be in arabic?

Comment: That depends on the name of your `mo` files.Try it, if you are not sure.

Comment: I only want to change the front-end language to arabic, not the back-end (my wordpress admin panel) thus only my theme language, so if i understood well: i have to modify the functions.php of my theme and add the following:is_admin() or add_filter( 'locale', function() {
    return 'ar-AR';
});

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just try it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your simplest option would be to update your installation using the localized version of WordPress for your [native language](http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/) (and making sure that `WPLANG` remains set accordingly), and then to use a plugin such as:

- [English WordPress Admin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/english-wp-admin/)
- [Admin in English](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-in-english/), or
- [WP Native Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/)

... in order to switch just the admin interface to English.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete and a better solution to only change theme (front-end) or plugin language. It even works for changing even a specific page/post etc. language as well.

*TLDR;* There is a filter called `locale`, which determines which language to load. You can change to your specific language based on the conditions that you prefer.

**Changing only Theme language, or based on other conditions, without touching the admin dashboard language.**

```
add_filter('locale', function($locale) {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $locale; // Leave default language if it is admin side.
    }

    // You can load language based on any conditional tags here, like, is_page(), is_singular(), is_archive() etc.
    // I want to change the language for all front end in this particular example.

    $locale = 'en_US'; // Change to your required language. The language must be installed and loaded.

    return $locale; // Return language to be used.

});
```

Before you change the language, you may need to load that language first.

In your theme or child theme, load the custom language by using this snippet.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {

    // Assuming your language files are in /wp-content/themes/your-theme/languages
    // Don't forget to change 'text-domain' to your theme text-domain.

    // For Theme.
    load_theme_textdomain( 'text-domain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // For Child Theme
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Remove the load_child_theme_textdomain if you are using it for the main theme,
    // OR Remove load_theme_textdomain if you are loading child theme language.

});
```

Similarly, you can change language based on URL, or for your plugin page, etc.

Hope it'll help. OR let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

1.Download jquery translate script from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/downloads/list)

2.How it works ( [doc](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/General),  [live test](http://jsbin.com/layab/1/)  )

```
<?php
function ravs_frontend_translate_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'translate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.translate.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0.0.1', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ravs_frontend_translate_script' );


function ravs_translate_webpage_fx(){
?>
<script>
    // run script after both script load for translate webpage
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          //from english to german:
          jQuery('body').translate( 'ar' );
        });
</script>
<?php
add_action('wp_footer','ravs_translate_webpage_fx', 999 ); // make sure this hook run after jquery-translate include in webpage
```

Comment: But that's using Google to translate the page isn't it, not using the .po files he already has?

Comment: @Rup Yes it is using google traslator not .po file. May be this is possible that .po file not contain  translation for a random word then `_e()` simple echo it while google translator convert whole webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code snippet that you can use to change the language dynamically in WordPress:

```
add_filter('locale', 'change_user_lang');
function change_user_lang($locale)
{
    if (is_admin()) return 'en_US'; // set the admin language to English
    // your custom language logic here, e.g.:
    // if (some condition) return 'fr_FR'; // set the language to French
    // if (some other condition) return 'de_DE'; // set the language to German

    return $locale; // return the original language if no conditions are met
}
```