# Changing the language of a single page

Tags: translation, multi-language, language

I have a wordpress site in a language that aligns RTL, but some pages are in English. These pages look terrible, however, because the English text is aligned with the RTL language, and punctuation, etc. appear on the wrong the side.

How can I set the language for a single page or several individual pages?

Answer (score 5):

The [`locale`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale) filter that allows you to set the locale specifically. You can check the current page, and alter the value based on that.

```
add_filter('locale', 'change_my_locale');
function change_my_locale( $locale ) {
    if ( is_page('slug-here') ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }
    return $locale;
}
```

Comment: Which file should I add this code to?

Comment: You can create must use plugin with following code and place it in wp-content/mu-plugins folder. https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins.

Alternative if you can modify theme, you can use functions.php file of your theme. Note that after updating this theme, your custom code will lost.
So you need to create child theme to avoid this https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I added this to my functions.php, inserting the page slug, and nothing happened.

Comment: @Null_Error Try and use `true` in the conditional, to check if the problem is with the `is_page()` or the locale itself.

Comment: You can't use functions.php for it, sorry. Theme loads too late for this hook

Comment: This does not work because `is_page()` will not work until after the main query is executed.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `locale` hook to solve your task.

Important note that you can't add it in theme and use `is_page` function, because it will define later.

So you have to create [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or [must use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) with url parsing this way:

```
add_filter('locale', function($locale) {
    $path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");

    // get last part as slug
    $arr = explode("/", $path);
    $slug = end($arr);

    if($slug === 'MY_SLUG')
      return 'ru_RU';

    return $locale;
});
```

Related answer: [Change locale at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-at-runtime)

Comment: Well, on doing ome further testing, it appears this code changes the entire website's language, not just that one page.

Comment: You right. I've updated my answer and tested it on my test blog installation. It seems everything working. Try it, please

Comment: I don't understand the term _"wrong"_ here. Your approach is the same, using the `locale` filter. I didn't test it specifically with the `is_page()` function, but if it's too soon to use `is_page()`, then it simply can't be done.

Comment: I've updated my anwser. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar for translation & direction purposes.

By defining $direction for each post, 'ltr' or 'rtl'...using [this simple plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contents-direction/) ...
I edited the plugin by adding following action to plugin.php file:

```
add_action('wp', function($locale){
    // get post meta from database, which is generated by the plugin
    global $post;
    $direction = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'os_custom_box_for_rtl', true);
    // set locale language based on post meta
    $locale = ($direction == 'rtl')? 'ar':'en_US'; // ...or use your own locale codes
    // if not admin area, do switch! it will work for frontend only per specific page/post
    is_admin() or switch_to_locale( $locale );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix for the problem of timing in the solution by @jack-johansson:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
  if ( is_page('slug-here') ) {
    add_filter('locale', function( $locale ) {
      return 'en_US';
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work to change the html tag lang attribute if the Site Language is set to something other than the default.