# How to Change the Wordpress Locale with the 'locale' Filter?

Tags: filters, language

I am not sure if I am doing this the right way but I want to avoid using a plugin. I have links on my page to change languages between Spanish and English. I am taking care of everything but when I get the date of the post, it is formatted in the locale of the Wordpress site, for instance:

> September 21, 2017

From the Wordpress Codex I found [this code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale) to change the locale via a filter.

So I ended up writing this ($language is a global variable that holds the language currently selected by the user):

```
function set_my_locale( $lang ) {
global $language;
if ( $language == SPANISH_LOCALE) {
    // set to Spanish
    return 'es_ES';
} 
else if ( $language == ENGLISH_LOCALE) {
    // set to English
    return 'en_US';
}
}
add_filter('locale','set_my_locale');
```

The function gets called and nothing is changed, the date is still shown in English.

Oh, I do have es_ES.mo and es_ES.po files inside the languages folder and I can switch to Spanish in the admin interface, so they are correctly installed.

I have run out of ideas, any clues why the dates are displayed in English regardless of what I do?

Comment: Did a bit more investigation and here's an interesting bit. In Wordpress:

Settings --> General

If Spanish is the language selected in 'Site Language' and my $language  variable is set to SPANISH_LOCALE and I try to switch the dropdown to 'English', when I click save settings, it goes back to 'Spanish:

https://goo.gl/Kw9QT5

 But notice that the admin menu on the left is still in English. WTF.

Comment: Figured it out, no need to use a filter to change the locale, simply use switch_to_locale() instead:

  if ($language == 'ES') {
   switch_to_locale('es_ES');
  }
  else if ($language='EN') {
   switch_to_locale('en_EN');
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change locale manually at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-manually-at-runtime)