# How to pass a variable into an add_filter() function?

Tags: php

I have this code here:

```
$pageLanguage = strtolower($pageMetadata["language"]); 

$languageArray = array ("afrikaans" => "af", "dutch" => "nl", "french" => "fr", "german" => "de", "spanish" => "es"); 

$updatedLanguage = $languageArray[$pageLanguage];

add_filter('locale', 'change_my_locale');
function change_my_locale( $locale ) {
  $locale = $updatedLanguage;
  return $locale;
}
```

I would like to know how to pass the variable $updatedLanguage into the change_my_locale() function please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you’re trying to do? In your example you would just define the variable inside the function.

Comment: Yes sorry I understand that I could move that variable as it is written into the function. I am getting the value of $updatedLanguage from other code that can't go into the function, I have updated the question with the extra code.

Basically, I getting the language of the page from the $pageMetadata array, and then want to update it using the filter. Is this the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anonymous function and pass the variable to it with `use`.

```
$updatedLanguage = $languageArray[$pageLanguage] ?? '';
if ( $updatedLanguage ) {
    add_filter('locale', function($locale) use ($updatedLanguage) {
        return $updatedLanguage;
    });
}
```

If you're changing the locale at runtime, then you may want to look here [Change locale manually at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-manually-at-runtime), where it is noted that the change could have a performance impact. Also, you may need to do the change early enough in the WP loading sequence so that the correct translation file gets loaded - if it something that you need.