# Obtain a list of available translations

Tags: translation

In answering this question: [Change language by clicking a button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/change-language-by-clicking-a-button/57503#57503). It was necessary to obtain a list of languages for which translations were available (i.e. their po/mo files were present in `wp-content/languages`).

### So how can you obtain that list?

Clearly by 'available' we can only mean that their `po/mo` files are present - and it's not a concern if every plug-in also provides a translation for that language (interesting to see how you might do this though).

The list was originally intended for us in a drop-down, whereby a user could select from a list of (available) languages. So the human readable form of the language *as well* would be a bonus. But I think this is probably not possible.

View the question linked to above for demonstration of the current method used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a list of available languages with `get_available_languages( $dir )`. It returns an array with all `.mo` files where the names does not start with `'continents-cities'`, `'ms-'` or `admin-`.

To get a readable name for the file use `format_code_lang( $code )`.

If you scan a directory for language files and get an array like `array( 'de_DE', 'tr_TR' )` this function will build <s>translated</s> names for the languages: `German` and `Turkish`.