# Which language files are loaded?

Tags: multi-language, debug, language, wp-debug

Is there a way to print a list of the loaded language files for debugging reasons?

Comment: I think this should help you out. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57606/obtain-a-list-of-available-translations

Comment: Try [Debug Translations](https://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/).

Comment: Thx for the help.

Comment: @fuxia Looks like your link is broken. Is your plugin still available somewhere? Or would you recommend something else now?

Comment: Thanks for the notice, @NathanArthur. I'll try to find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to the comments I found the plugin: **[Debug MO Translations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-mo-translations/)**

It returns a list of all searched and loaded MO files. The source code is provided on github: https://github.com/closemarketing/debug-mo-translations

Comment: That's just a copy of my plugin.

Comment: I look through you plugins, which one is it?

Comment: The one I mentioned in my comment to your question. The source code of the copy has my name on it.

Comment: I didn't mention it cuz it seems that there is no copy to find on https://wordpress.org/plugins/