# Adding Language Switcher in header , WP

Tags: language

Currently, I'm building multi languages blog. 
As I know, almost WP language translator plugins are based on .po & .mo files. 
here is a problem.
A new language what I'm going to add does not exist with .po & .mo files, it's just a dialect(local) language.

That's why I defined in php and grab the language.php files as below code.

**header.php**

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>/?lang=newlanguage"> New Language</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>/?lang=eng">English</a>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang'];
if ( $_SESSION['language'] == 'newlanguage' ) {
require (TEMPLATEPATH .'/languages/new-language.php');
}
else {
require (TEMPLATEPATH .'/languages/english.php');  // default language
} ?>
```

the problem is it doesn't work,
if I load to the new page, "new-language" is disappear and it automatically changes to the default language.

My question is Can someone guide me to the right way/codes with developer solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the language used by wordpress from a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85690/how-to-update-the-language-used-by-wordpress-from-a-plugin)

Comment: [Please take a look at this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85690/how-to-update-the-language-used-by-wordpress-from-a-plugin/85693#85693). Your question was already asked and answered two times.

Comment: If the `.po` file, and its correspondent `.mo`, don't exist, you have to [create it yourself](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57243/12615).

Comment: @ronaldtgi, please add your solution as an Answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the language used by wordpress from a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85690/how-to-update-the-language-used-by-wordpress-from-a-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wcm-user-language-switcher 
I tried wcm language switcher, it only supports for users, not for guest who are not logged in. anyway thanks to kaiser & brasofilo.

Finally, I got a solution with theme switcher plugin 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher 
I duplicate my theme and keep one is default, then create next one for new-language.
even it takes more space in hosting, it was definitely what I need.

just add to header.php as the follow codes
`<?php  wp_theme_switcher(); ?> or <?php  wp_theme_switcher('dropdown'); ?>`

it allowed for all users,guests and also eveyone can switch without logging in. 
theme switcher plugin also provide for sidebar widget with dropdown & lists style.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/language-switcher/

Language Switcher allows you to map urls of alternative languages for Post Types and Taxonomies.

Additionally it allows you to filter archive pages by language.

It is a good option if your multi-language architecture includes different wordpress installations but it also works for centralized architecture with all the content under the same installation.